# Two attributes in primary key SQL (Reference foreign key to this key)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have problem with SQL when I create table. 
For example:

```
/* lekovi */
create table lekovi
(
    kid number(5),
    Isifra number(10),
    lime varchar2(50),
    sostav varchar2(500),

    primary key (kid, Isifra),
    foreign key (kid) references kompanii (kid)
)

/* recepti */
create table recepti
( 
    kid number(5),
    Isifra number(10),
    dembg number(13),
    pembg number(13),
    datum varchar2(50),
    doza varchar2(500),

    primary key (kid, Isifra, dembg, pembg), <---
    foreign key (kid, Isifra) references lekovi (kid, Isifra), <---
    foreign key (dembg) references doktori (dembg),
    foreign key (pembg) references pacienti (pembg)
)
```

I have two tables `lekovi` and `recepti`.

In table `lekovi` I have primary key `(kid, Isifra)`. When I reference from `recepti` (mark in code with <---) I have problem because I show how two individual keys rather than as a composite. SQL is written in ORACLE.

How to solve this problem with keys?

Comment: Not clear really what is your problem ? What do you want to get ?

Comment: How to reference composite foreign key from "recepti" to "lekovi"?

Answer (score 0):

> > How to reference composite foreign key from "recepti" to "lekovi"?

Exactly as you do. Foreign key should have the same column content as the referenced key (number of columns, and position/datatype).

```
SQL> create table lekovi (
  2  kid number(5),
  3  Isifra number(10),
  4  lime varchar2(50),
  5  sostav varchar2(500),
  6  primary key (kid, Isifra)
  7  )
  8  /

Table created.

SQL> create table recepti (
  2  kid number(5),
  3  Isifra number(10),
  4  dembg number(13),
  5  pembg number(13),
  6  datum varchar2(50),
  7  doza varchar2(500),
  8  primary key (kid, Isifra, dembg, pembg),
  9  foreign key (kid, Isifra)
 10  references lekovi (kid, Isifra)
 11  )
 12  /

Table created.
```

Comment: But when I insert data to table "recepti" I see this form http://prntscr.com/35kg21

But I have put one ID who reference to lekovi not two text field.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how the web form you reference is related to your question. You created composite primary key in lekovi table. All foreign keys referencing this promary key must have the same structure as PK they reference - this is a law of RDBMS by design. If you need to create foreign keys referencing Key and Isifra columns separately you must reference other PKs in other tables with correspondent structure. But you should make this decision depends on your business requirements.